# Windows unattended setup failed - 'specified image file does not exist'

Tags: windows, windows-10, unattended, microsoft

I am trying to do an unattended install of Windows 10 Professional using an answer XML file I created. I'm booting off a USB, and receiving the error:

Windows could not collect information for [DataImage1] because the specified image file [\sources\MyImageFile.wim] does not exist.

This is my XML for reference: https://pastebin.com/PuDJ5998

I'm using ImgBurn to create my ISO (from boot, efi, sources, support, etc), and Rufus to create a bootable USB drive from this ISO.

I have confirmed that the .wim file is where I've specified it on the USB, and I have tried using /, \, and removing the first slash before 'sources' in the XML 'InstallFrom' option.

Any thoughts on what my issue would be?

Comment: I'll give it a try @HarryJohnston

Comment: @HarryJohnston I have tried removing the <InstallFrom> option in the .xml, and renaming the .wim to install.wim. This leaves me with the error: 'Windows could not process the <ImageInstall> setting in the unattend answer file.' Any ideas?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I don't have a setup folder currently, nor does one come with any Windows iso I've ever seen - is this something I need to create?

Comment: It is currently in root\sources. This is correct?

Comment: Oh.  Is this a data image rather than an operating system image?

Comment: This is indeed a data image instead of an OS image @HarryJohnston

Comment: D'oh!  Sorry, I misunderstood.  In that case, renaming it to `install.wim` would definitely *not* be a good idea.  And if you've copied it over the operating system image you'll need to put the original OS image back.

Comment: Starting again, then: you have `MyImageFile.wim` in the `sources` folder.  The documentation says that relative paths are allowed but is unclear as to whether the path is relative to `setup.exe` or to the current directory.  I believe you've already tried `sources\MyImageFile.wim` and it didn't work; do you know what the current directory is when you run `setup.exe` ?

Comment: ... actually there is some ambiguity there, perhaps it should just be `MyImageFile.wim` ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston So when you say I'll need to put the original OS image back, you mean retrieve the install.wim from the original Windows 10 ISO I was using, and put that in sources, as well as MyImageFile.wim? I think I will also try adding MyImageFile.wim to sources, as well as root, and simply setting path as "MyImageFile.wim", and see how that goes.

Comment: Yes.  Good luck!  If that works, you could then try putting the file in only one of the two places to see which one it is actually using.  And if you have time, please post a self-answer so future readers will know what to do.

Comment: Of course! I'll self-answer if it goes well. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Still no dice, back to the original error message. Can't find a file that I can see in the specified location.

Comment: Does it work if you specify the full path, including the drive letter?  (That wouldn't be a good solution but it might help narrow down the cause.)

Answer (score -1):

Check file integrity. It may be damaged and therefore installation does not occur. Also save a backup copy of the data on your computer so that the installation does not lead to data loss. This is given your existing problems.